# hibernate dialect for oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm using hibernate in my spring mvc project and I want to connect to oracle 12c database. I used `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect`, but, this returns me `org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]`. How can I set dialect for oracle 12c?
I'm using hibernate `4.3.9`.

Answer (score 17):

`org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect` can be used with hibernate-core version 5.0

See: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Oracle12cDialect.html

Comment: I think that more details will be good. Add some additional links to documentation and some explanations will be great also.

Comment: While link-only answers are generally against SO policy, this is a great concise answer

Comment: `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect` cannot be used below Hibernate 5.0. This class is absent from Hibernate 4.3 (previous release prior to 5.0) and lower as can be seen in the [4.3 javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/).

Answer (score 13):

Try to use `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`, seems to be the highest possible version in Hibernate `4.3.9`.

A dialect for 12c seems to be present in later versions, see [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9044).

Comment: You mean `Oracle10gDialect` works for oracle 12c same as 11g?

Comment: @hamed: Yes, it should work (apart from some version specific details).

Comment: For me Oracle10gDialect works for oracle 12c same as 11g.
Thank you very much wjans!

Answer (score 0):

(Maven) for:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

You might want to add this dialect:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
```