# Using Hibernate Oracle10g dialect for Oracle12c

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g, oracle12c

Hibernate version 4.3.0 does not support Oracle 12c dialect. Oracle 10g dialect works for 12c but is there a downside of doing this?. Does using mismatched dialect and database version impact performance?, The quality of the SQL's fired?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hibernate dialect for oracle 12c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698651/hibernate-dialect-for-oracle-12c)

Comment: @Leozeo The question you have suggested does not talk about the implications of using different versions of dialect and database. It only says that oracle 10g dialect works for Oracle 12c database which I have already mentioned using in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to take the source of `Oracle12cDialect` and add it to your application's source with any modifications to make it compliant with Hibernate 4.3.  All you need to do is to manually add the `hibernate.dialect` property and specify the name of your custom Oracle 12 dialect class.

The `Oracle12cDialect` in Hibernate 5.2 provides the following differences from 10g:

- Accounts for Oracle's deprecated support for `LONGVARBINARY` to prefer `BLOB`.
- It uses a SQL2008 compliant limit handler implementation where-as the 10g doesn't.
- Recommends native identifier generation as `sequence`
- Specifies its own identity support algorithm.

Comment: Has anyone managed to extract the 12c dialect from Hibernate 5 and merged with with Hibernate 4 ?